# Log middle-ware gets 200 response code when it is actually a 500

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I am working on a ASP.Net Core Web API project and I want to log all the requests and 500 server errors.

I used custom middleware to log requests, and it is defined in the startup.cs as:

```
app.UseMiddleware<logMiddleware>();
```

I also defined an Exception handler to capture server errors in the startup.cs:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => {
    builder.Run(async context => {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (error != null) {
            logService logger = new logService(conf);
            await logger.logError(error, context);
        }
    });
});
```

I keep the request information in error logs, so I don't need to save the request log when the response code is 500, so I added a check into request log function to filter errors:

```
public async Task logRequestAsync(HttpContext context) {
    if (context.Response.StatusCode != 500) {
        //do things
    }
}
```

The problem is the Response.StatusCode returns as 200 instead of 500. Probably it runs before the API call's function is completed and the server error happens later in the runtime.

Is there a way to move the "request log" process to the point where the response is created instead of the beginning of the API request?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this post [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/) and also consider using [Global Exception Handling for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/JosephWoodward/GlobalExceptionHandlerDotNet) `NuGet` package?

Comment: Just confirming if you are checking the `context.Response.StatusCode != 500` after the `await _next.Invoke(context);` in the `logMiddleware`. Also, I guess, `logMiddleware` is the first one in the chain, is that right?

Comment: @ShahzadHassan that was the problem, thank you so much

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad I was able to help